# Find the top 10 records from an array on the basis of highest score

Tags: php, arrays, json, sorting

I can't figure it out on how to fetch top 10 records from an array on the basis of the highest score calculation using php. I fetch the records out from the table, perform the calculation and store the result in an array name score and associating with rest of the query string(Array) so I can carry that calculation into JSON. My issue is I only need to carried top 10 records which has the highest score.

```
    $gold=$_GET['gold_input'];
    $silver=$_GET['silver_input'];
    $bronze=$_GET['bronze_input'];
    $gdp_value=$_GET['gdp_checked'];


    $link = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '','coa123cdb');
    $myArray = array();

    $query = "SELECT  * FROM  coa123cdb.Country";

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query)
    or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($link));

    $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
    if ($result = $link->query($query)) {
    $tempArray = array();
    $score=array();

    $counter=0  ;
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

      $tempArray['country_name'] = $row['country_name'];
      $tempArray['gdp']=$row['gdp'];
      $tempArray['population']=$row['population'];
      $tempArray['gold']=$row['gold'];
      $tempArray['silver']=$row['silver'];
      $tempArray['bronze']=$row['bronze'];

                if($gdp_value==0)
            {
                        $score=($bronze*$tempArray['bronze'])+($silver*$tempArray['silver'])+($silver*$tempArray['gold']);

            }
            else
            {
            $score=($bronze*$tempArray[6]+$silver*$tempArray[5]+$silver*$tempArray[4])*$tempArray[1]/$tempArray[2]/10000;
            }
            $tempArray['score']=$score;
            $data[]=$tempArray;
            $counter++;
        }


       echo json_encode($data);
}

$result->close();
$link->close();
```

Please advise what should I need to do in order to pass only top 10 records from an array to JSON object.

Comment: Limiting the query and sorting in SQL would be good, but only if you're not going to use the result later. It would also require calculating score in the SQL query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I've understood you correctly and I think that the best solution would be sorting your array and take first 10 values.

To sort an array there are lots of functions. Because I'm too lazy to learn them all I prefer [`usort()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), which gives me full control what is being done. You can sort by your 'score' field. Perhaps somebody would find a better function.

To take first 10 elements, you can use simple `for` loop.

If you do not wish to sort the source array, you can always make a copy of it.

Comment: how am I gonna refer the element score in the usort because its usually take the name of an array? and shall I do the sorting inside the loop or outside the loop?

Comment: The `usort()` accepts two parameters. The second one is a string, that is your comparing function name (`cmp` in the manual examples). You need to declare this function and it accepts two parameters, which are array cells that are going to be compare -- you compare "score" in this `cmp` function (or whatever you name it), not in the `usort` itself! You would compare not `$a > $b` but `$a["score"] > $b["score"]`.

Comment: @ShoaibSuleman Please take a look at the [similar example](http://pl1.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php#88130) -- this sorts on many criteria, you just need one, but you will realize how the array keys should be considered.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, it's much better idea to create complex MySQL query.

MySQL computing score will be almost free, comparising with cost of returning of all results and computing in php.

I suggest create sql query + "order by score limit 10".

```sql
SELECT  *,CASE gdp
WHEN 0 THEN bronze*silver
ELSE bronze*silver / 1000
END as score FROM coa123cdb.Country order by score desc limit 0,10
```

This code is for switching between score compute types

```
CASE gdp
WHEN 0 THEN bronze*silver
ELSE bronze*silver / 1000
END
```

Comment: to be honest I am not good with sql statements that is why I wants to do it via php and actually this is one of the requirement as well that it should done via code instead of sql statement

Comment: Thanks for the query, however just let you aware that user inputs the value on the form and on the basis calculation is performed, I am not sure how the sql will work considering if user has to input the values

Comment: You can pass them using php prepare statement. Check SO for examples.

Answer (score 1):

You have to sort your array first then.. put limit in fetching the records 
try something like this

```
  ---- your code above it ---

        $tempArray['score']=$score;
        $data[]=$tempArray;
        foreach($data as $value)
        {
           $score[]  = $value['score']
        }
        array_multisort($score, SORT_DESC,$data);

        $i = 0;
        $newArray = array();
        foreach($data as $value)
        {
            if($i < 10)
            {
                $newArray[] = $value;
            }
            $i++;
        }  


  --- code below----------
```

`$newArray` will contain the required array ...

You can read more about [array_multisort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

Hope it helps you

Comment: I think there's something wrong in the first `foreach`. You're assigning the same `$score` variable different values. I think `$score[] = ...` should be used.

Comment: I used the usort first to sort the array on the score basis and then flip around the array to get the top 10 score elements...works for me so thanks for all your answers

Answer (score 0):

Since the `ORDER BY...LIMIT` method is more efficient, I would go for that.
See comments inside code for a short explanation.

```
/* Initialize variables */
$gold      = $_GET["gold_input"];
$silver    = $_GET["silver_input"];
$bronze    = $_GET["bronze_input"];
$gdp_value = $_GET["gdp_checked"];
$data = array();

/* Construct the query based on user input.
   The query should calculate the 'score' (taking '$gdp_value' into account)
   and then return the 10 highest scoring entries.
   The returned columns include all columns present in the 'Country' table
   plus an extra column named 'score' (which contains the calculated score).*/
$scoreFormula = ($gdp_value == 0)
        ? "((" . $bronze . " * bronze) + (" . $silver . " * silver) + (" . $gold . " * gold))";
        : "(((" . $bronze . " * bronze) + (" . $silver . " * silver) + (" . $gold . " * gold)) * (gdp / (population * 10000)))";
$query = "SELECT Country.*, " . $scoreFormula . " AS score
            FROM Country
            ORBER BY score DESC
            LIMIT 10";

/* Connect to the DB and execute the query */
$link = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "coa123cdb");
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query)
    or die("Error: " . mysqli_error($link));

/* Put the results into the '$data' array */
$row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
forEach ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

/* Release resources */
$result->close();
$link->close();

/* Return the data */
echo(json_encode($data));
```

**NOTE**:
The code is for illustration purposes only. It is always a bad, **bad**, **BAD** idea to put unfiltered user-input into an SQL statement. You should use a **[prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)** instead.

Comment: @Shoaib Suleman: I wonder why my answer got "unaccepted". If the requirements have changed, it might be better to update your question or post a new one (if the new requirements require a different solution).